# Using XAJAX and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, xajax

I'm trying to use XAJAX % WordPress together. I've created and tested my XAJAX app and everything works fine. But when I include the XAJAX core into my WordPress theme I get this error:

> Output has already been sent to the browser at E:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\wp\wp-content\themes\mytheme\header.php:2. Please make sure the command $xajax->processRequest() is placed before this.

Anyone has any experience with this?

I really appreciate your help.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like XAJAX is trying to set some headers, but it's running after content has been sent to the visitor. Find `processRequest()` and make sure it's not after any output (like HTML)